# Django block request

Tags: django

I have a problem with my website. there it is :

No problem in this case :

- User A do a request.
- Django server update data...
- Object 1 is updated.
- Object 2 is updated.
- Object 3 is updated.
- Django render the result.
- User A do a request.

Problem apear in this case :

- User A do a request.
- Django server update data...
- Object 1 is updated.
- Object 2 is updated.
- **User A do another request !**
- **User A do another request !**
- Django render the result.

the problem is that if the user makes a request while the server has not finished working, the server stop the process and data are no longer good.

I think i have to block client side (by displaying a loading message for exemple) but i want to be sur the user **cant** make a request on the server if another treatemment still working.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have a long running process, and the user gets tired of waiting, clicks on "stop" in the browser; the other scenario is - user opens another tab and sends the same request again.

A few ways to solve this problem.

1. Use the [transaction middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/?from=olddocs) to prevent your db objects from being corrupted if the request is interrupted.
2. Use a task queue like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/index.html). At the first request, offload your task to the queue/broker. Send the user a message that their request has been accepted for processing. Now the user is free to send a duplicate request. If they do, you can check what is the status of the queue and reject the duplicate requests.